# Passing a method as an argument for another method

Tags: vb.net, delegates

Passing a method as an argument for another method:

```
Public Sub NewThread(Method As Action)
    Me.TaskThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(Method))
End Sub
```

Results for error:

> *Error    BC32008:* *"Delegate 'ThreadStart' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor."*

**And**

```
Public Sub NewThread(Method As Action)
    Me.TaskThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Method))
End Sub
```

Results for error:

> *Error    BC30577:* *"'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)."*

What went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `Thread` expects a *delegate*. Traditionally, if you have a method, say, `MyMethod`:

```
Private Sub MyMethod()
    ' Do stuff.
End Sub
```

You'd call the constructor as follows:

```
Me.TaskThread = New Thread(AddressOf MyMethod)
```

Notice that `AddressOf` is to be followed by the *name of the method* (without parentheses). But since you have the method as a delegate parameter (of type `Action`), you need to pass as a lambda expression like this:

```
Me.TaskThread = New Thread(Sub() Method())
```

Comment: This is quite surprising, as `Action` is supposed to be a delegate.  (That is, the declaration per the documentation is exactly `Public Delegate Sub Action()`.)  It seems that the issue might be that it's not willing to convert an `Action` delegate to a `ThreadStart` delegate even though they have the same signature.  I wouldn't normally suggest turning `Option Strict Off`, but I suspect that conversion might get done for you if you do so.  You might also try seeing if `CType(MyMethod, ThreadStart)` works.